# How to show thumbnail in Google search result

Tags: web-applications, seo, googlebot

I'm wondering why Google shows thumbnail image in search results for one site and doesn't show it for another? E.g. when I google [kfc chicken recipe](https://www.google.com/#hl=ru&gs_rn=8&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=7NZbA4kT1AWo_MQB_C317Q&pq=fry%20recipe&cp=10&gs_id=5c&xhr=t&q=kfc+chicken+recipe&es_nrs=true&pf=p&newwindow=1&sclient=psy-ab&oq=kfc+chicke+recipe&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44770516,d.bGE&fp=55e8d373b3323a76&biw=1280&bih=963) I can see thumbnail for www.food.com and cannot see it for www.tastyappetite.net.

I've tried to google this question but I only found [this article](http://googlecustomsearch.blogspot.com/2011/11/thumbnail-images-in-search-results-no.html) that says Google does it automatically and I don't need to worry about it.

There are any recommendations how to hint to Google that this is thumbnail for the page?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of informations showed by Google is called "**microdatas**". You can inform in your code  **what google has to understand of it**. As said by Carte Cole, [schema.org](http://schema.org) shows you multiple possibilities of microdatas.

Take an exemple, your example.
You took a recipe from fried chicken, and google displays a photo of friend chiken, grades of it and cooking preparation time. In schema.org, you can find all microdatas you can give google for a recipe : [microdatas of recipe](http://schema.org/Recipe). There are many (many, MANY) cases where microdatas are useful (person, recipe, places...).

By the way, **it's just some HTML code to add to your actual code**, as used in example in the bottom of the preview link.

> ex for preparation time : Cook time: `<meta itemprop="cookTime" content="PT1H">1 hour`

Microdatas are very useful for **a great SEO strategy**. It permits Google to **well understand your content**, then, well qualified, it will be up in search engines results pages.

More over, a well qualified pages with microdata is beautifully displayed in google results, **it keeps customers eyes** !

Answer (score 0):

Thats actually for google custom search not for the main Google domain. What you are probably looking for is marking up your data with http://schema.org which allows them to display more complete information about whats on the page because its in a known format